# How to draw lines progressively in cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, user-interface, cocos2d-iphone

Konami develops some truly beautiful UIs for their Bemani series. One of the tricks they use is to progressively draw lines where UI elements will appear a split second before they actually appear. You can see it very clearly in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J4aLmrwWEUk&feature=related

What is the best way to do this with cocos2D? As a bonus, what would be the best way to do this with a non-cocos2d game on iOS?

Comment: I would also ask this question on the Cocos2D forum here: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/

Comment: Thanks. Usually I post there, but I rarely get a straight answer. I've been getting much better results on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The best way should be overwriting the draw method in each node you want.

You can get the dimensions of the node (look the texture2d) and with that you can create a bounding box.

Then in the draw method you could use an internal variable and increment it.

- While it is over a value you draw with [super draw]
- When it is less you use glDrawLines functions (check the draw primitives example) and with the variable you set the length of the line.

Comment: I know how to get the bounds and draw lines...what I mean to ask is if there is a convenience method or class for drawing those lines gradually, especially if it involves curves or paths.

Comment: What do you mean gradually? If you want curves, check this out: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3913/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-2